# Fix location datacube-explorer

Tags: open-data-cube

after indexing and add data to data cube. I want to show datasets in data cube-explorer but in the map affiche a wrong country how can I fix the location

Answer (score 0):

We might need more information to answer properly.

But the map is automatically centered on the area of the world that your datasets cover, so if it's showing a random map location without your datasets, you may not have any datasets to display?

Some things you could check:

1. Check that your datasets indexed correctly. Do they show up in normal datacube searches without Explorer?
2. Make sure you've run `cubedash-gen` after indexing (see [explorer setup](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-explorer/#summary-generation)) so that Explorer's maps are up-to-date. It will say if there are errors, and print the number of datasets it scans.

3. If there are datasets being displayed in Explorer's map, but it's the wrong location in the world, your datasets might have the wrong geo extent information in their metadata. Or the wrong CRS.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked